# Define $T(2^n) = T(2^n/n) + 1$ with $T(1) = 1$ . Is $T(2^n)∈ Θ(n) ?$

Tags: recurrence-relations, asymptotics, computer-science, computational-complexity

I'm trying to solve the following problem $:$

> Define $T(2^n) = T(2^n/n) + 1$ with  $T(1) = 1$ . Is $T(2^n)∈ Θ(n) ?$

If I convert this recurrence relation into $:$

> Define  $T(k) = T(k/log_2k) + 1$ with  $T(2) = 1$ . Is $T(k)∈
>  Θ(log_2k) ?$
>   with assumption $k = 2^n$

---

Since if $T(n)=aT(n/b)+f(n),$ it would be of order $Θ(logn),$ if $a==1$ and $f(n)==1.$ Using master theorem $,$ I'm guessing $.$

Can you explain in formal way, please?

Comment: The question looks strange.  With $T(n) = T(2^n/n) + 1$, are you saying $T(2) = T(2) + 1$ and $T(4) = T(4) + 1$ and $T(8) = T(32) + 1$?

Comment: exactly , you are right .

Comment: No. $T(k)=\Theta(\frac {\log k} {\log\log k})$ since $\log$ is slow growing.